# Why does Moment.js day ends at 22:59:59.999Z?

Tags: javascript, time, timestamp, momentjs

When using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to get the [end of](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) a day, it returns 22:59:59.999Z:

```
moment('2013-W06-5').endOf('day') // 2013-02-08T22:59:59.999Z
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/nS6o5F.

Can anyone please explain why the day doesn't end at 23:59:59.999Z?

I don't think Moment.js handles it wrong. Maybe it's something about daylight saving time (writing from German)?

Comment: From the docs, [`endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) set the moment to `23:59:59.999`, I don't think it is a bug, probably something in your code, you need to share it to let us help you further.

Comment: I don't think its a bug either. Added source code and link to Plunker to original post.

Comment: The issue is the way you are showing the value inside your angular view. Convert moment object to string using [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) in your controller or use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) inside your view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

endOf is timezone aware.

Use .utc() and you get what you need:

```
$scope.output = moment('2013-W06-5').utc().endOf('day');
=> "2013-02-08T23:59:59.999Z"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BgcBpRmldQL7po4W4vFv?p=preview

Comment: OP was asking why it didn't display the 23. Answer really is that by default, moment parses and displays in local time. So for me, 22:59:59.999Z displayed as 06:59:59.999Z.

Comment: Would you post an answer using format() or angular-moment that could show the OP other alternatives?

Comment: This answer was perfect. The question was not about Angular - I just used it in Plunker.